# MySQL8.0 Workbench error when adding a connection

Tags: mysql

I'm new to window and mySQL. I installed mySQL 8.0. I turned on mySQL in system preferences.

Then I went into workbench, clicked to add a new connection and filled in the details: host is localhost; username is root; password is empty/nothing. Tested the connection and its all good.
Operation failed: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.testInstanceSettingByName.

I also can not access mySQL from the terminal.

I've googled and can't find anything. Has anyone got any ideas of what could be wrong something I could try to fix it.

Comment: Which OS are we talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 10 and I was facing the same error with wbAdmin.testInstanceSettingByName.

I had installed MySQL Server 8.0.23 (x64) and MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 (x64).

I then decided to uninstall just the MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 (x64) and reinstall it using version 8.0.11.

The error changed: it was asking me to add the value "C:\Windows\System32" to the PATH environment variable (system variables). It worked.

To edit environment variables, just search for "Environment" in the Control Panel or Start Menu. You should be able to find it from there.